# how to add name atrribute to the jqxwidget option box?

Tags: php, jquery, jqxcombobox

I'm currently working on a php application . In my search for drop-down menu with image support in it, I came across a exciting cross-browser library known as JQXWIDGET . It uses java script (jquery) to add html *input*s to the form. but when I submit the form , none of the input field are get to be shown in my $_POST array . I looked for the reason and it has some thing to do with the catch that none of the input fields that gotten created with this library has any name attribute with it . My question is , How can I add this name attribute to all the input fields that gets created this way.

Comment: May I suggest to add some of your html and phpcode? Otherwise we need to guess (needle/haystack). Common issue that causes this problem is that the form method is set to 'GET'.

Comment: I was going to add an image , but apparently it needed some extra points. anyway , the method I used to submit the form is 'POST' and i have attached a jqx-optionbox to a div element with the id='price_grade' . I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the example of the JQX website:

http://www.jqwidgets.com/submit-form-with-jqxlistbox/